# Google Cloud Pub/Sub on Google App Engine hits QPS limit too soon

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-pubsub

Around 90 or 100 calls per second to

`pubsub_client.projects().topics().publish(topic='projects/xxxx',body=body).execute(num_retries=0)`

per second from Google App Engine App to Google Cloud Pub/Sub, results in

`HttpError: <HttpError 429 when requesting https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxx:publish?alt=json returned "Request throttled due to user QPS limit being reached.">`

I know there is a limit on administrative operations at 100 QPS, but certainly publishing to a topic is not an administrative operation?  I know pub/sub should support millions of operations per second so I know there's something wrong.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.  I need to get up to at least 300 publishes per second, trying to streamline an existing implementation using pubsub.  I think this may be a bug with the implementation.

I am running this code on Google App Engine python 2.7 -- using the appengine runtime, not the flexible one as that's not approved for production code yet.

Answer (score 0):

Note that publisher quota is not in terms of QPS, but in terms of throughput. The default limit is 100MB/s. See the [Quotas documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas) for more details. Depending on the message size you are sending, you may be running into these limits.

The "user QPS limit being reached" message on a publish usually means one of three things:

1. You are publishing at a throughput that is higher than the default 100MB/s quota. If that is the case, then you can apply for more quota by clicking on the "Apply for higher quota" on the [Pub/Sub Quota](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/pubsub.googleapis.com/quotas) page.
2. You are not authenticated against the correct Cloud project. If you are authenticated in or running your Google App Engine instances in a Cloud project that differs from the one your topic is defined in, the quota you run into may not be defined in the project you expect. More information can be found in the [Google Application Defaults Credentials page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials).
3. You have manually set quota in the [Quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/pubsub.googleapis.com/quotas) and that is the limit you are running into.

Comment: 1) each message is about 100 bytes (it's a dict with a few keys/values converted to json and then b64encoded) so it's not that. 300*100 = 30kb/sec 2) I was using default credentials and have tried using specific credentials from a .json file, same problem in both cases. 3) haven't manually set a quota but will check that.  Here's a quick followup question: is there a limit on publishes to one topics? I'm publishing to just one topic.